# CSS and javascript only works after couple of seconds after loading of page

Tags: javascript, css, html

My website loads and only after few seconds I get for example functionality.

For example I have

```
<a href="news.php" class="home-page--news-box-button-wrapper">
   <div class="home-page--news-box-button-text-wrapper">
     <span class="home-page--news-box-button-text">Sve vijesti</span>
   </div>
   <div class="home-page--news-box-button-arrow-wrapper">
     <span>here goes arrow</span>
   </div>
</a>
```

And css has a simple transition

```
.home-page--news-box-button-wrapper {

    background-color: $red;
    transition: background-color 100ms;

    &:hover{
      background-color: $brown;

      .home-page--news-box-button-arrow-wrapper {

        text-align: center;
        height: 43px;
        transform: translateX(5px);
      }
    }
```

And hover only triggers after few seconds.

Did anyone had this problem before

Comment: do you have a lot of animations on the page?  if you do you may want to cut back: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/

Comment: Is initial background color of the div (.home-page--news-box-button-wrapper) red ? I mean, do you see red background as soon as it loads ?

Comment: yes initial is red as soon as it loads

Comment: You can check the frame rate of your page in chrome dev tools -> more tools -> rendering -> check the paint flashing and fps meter options

Comment: I get few paint flash and when it stops I can see entire page. How can I see what is that